# Chrome Extension: Looping through an array and producing sounds based on beats per minute

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, let's say I have an array like this and a for loop to iterate through it:

```
var song = ['A', 'A', 'A'];
for (let n = 0; n < song.length; n++) {
  // run 'the function' at 100 BPM...
  // what I tried:
  setTimeout(function() {
    the function // obviously this won't work
  }, beatsPerMinute);
}
```

I have a function already written that takes those letter strings and converts them into sound. The issue I am facing is timing. Currently, all the sounds fire at once.

How can I run 'the function', as accurately as possible, to beats per minute?

Comment: so setTimeout isn't accurate ?

Comment: is BeatsPerMinute Defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setTimeout()` function is non-blocking and will return immediately.

```
var song = ['A', 'A', 'A'];
var n = 0;
function makeSound() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        theFunction(song[n]);
        n++;
        if (n < song.length)
            makeSound();
    }, beatsPerMinute)
}
makeSound();
```